# Sql Server 2008 Replication "Generate Scripts" option not available

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

All,

On `Sql Server 2008`, I have `Transaction Replication` going from `Server1` to `Server3` (with `Server2` as `distribution`).

I have an option to `"Generate Scripts"` on `Publication` on `Server1`. But I **do not** have that option to `"Generate Scripts"` for `Subscription` on `Server3`.

But on a different set of servers (`Server6, Server7, Server8`) with replication I have options to `"Generate Scripts"` on both `Publication` and `Subscription`.

Both are `Sql Server 2008`, but the later has `Sql Serve 2008 R2` on it.

Could that be the reason? How do I get around it?

Thanks,
_UB

*Edit:Grammar, and more grammar.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are these push subscriptions?  If so, the Generate Scripts option will not be available on the subscribers.  To generate scripts for push subscriptions, right-click on the Publication on Server 1 -> *Generate Scripts...*  The generated script will contain T-SQL necessary to create the publication and the push subscriptions.

Pull subscriptions should have Generate Scripts option at the subscriber.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I'll check it out.

Comment: You are correct. It is that simple.  I was thrown off by `Subscription` (listings) shown at both `Publisher` and `Subscriber`. Also, `Generate Scripts` is not visible at Subscription level at the publisher. I had to script out the entire `Publication+Subscription` together. But I am glad know that now. _UB